# Cannot get dependencies/packages to be recognized in source files of ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

### Problem

I cannot get packages to be recognized in source files of ASP.NET application.

It doesn't matter if it is something generated using ASP.NET5 web starter, .NET team music store app, or my own from scratch.

What is wrong? See step 2 for screen shot of the problem.

### Details

- Windows 8.1 + updates VM
- Visual Studio 2015 CTP
- x86 Core Beta 2

How I feel someone can reproduce my problem.

Step 0: Clone a ASP.NET 5 application, in my case the mvcmusicstore
[image]

Step 1: Observe errors in my solution out of the box. I cannot build the project I just updated and cloned 
[image]

Step 2: Check out a class to see what is going on. This is the problem right here. Oh, okay, so maybe I'm missing dependencies still...
[image]

Step 3: [Wut](http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/275/9/2/what_the_hell_is_going_on_by_velica-d2zxdd3.jpg). The packages have been brought in by project.json!?! The image below is cropped, but the packages are there. See

[image]

Step 4: Existential crisis. Does someone have a tool or version I don't? 
[image]

Step 5: My project.json packages all have * to get the latest nightly builds. It looks like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/project.json). Could it be that my KRE is out of date? Well, I am using beta2. That's what `kvm upgrade` does. 
[image]

Step 6: Check nugget
[image]

Step 7: Try a kpm restore. Notice xunit.runner didn't get restored and my issue still remains. 
[image]

Step 8: Success (it works when you do this) 
Change all the dependencies to beta2 like he states and use nugget.org

### Attempts

- Reinstall VM
- Reinstall KVM
- Reinstall VS15 CTP
- Ask Microsoft EF/MVCMusic teams
- Delete KRE dependencies except for beta2
- Build application from scratch (issue appears)
- Tylenol from head banging and [this](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/234/765/b7e.jpg)
- My colleague reproduced my same problem

I have worked on this for days and I feel I am missing something obvious. If someone else has run into this problem, were you able to fix it? There are two possibilities:

- I am missing something obvious (my working assumption)
- The tools available to .NET devs at Microsoft are different and things that work for them will not work for me because the tools that are public still are too beta

Comment: Which NuGet feeds do you have configured? And from exactly where did you clone the MusicStore app? The problem seems to be that you have the MyGet.org/ aspnetvnextfeed enabled, but you really want to use just NuGet.org.

Comment: I have it configured for the nightly builds (which is most up to date stuff). However, it is broke either NuGet.org or nightly builds when I do a kpm restore. :-/

Comment: Then you need to pull MusicStore from the `dev` branch. The default branch is `master`, which is `beta2`.

Comment: That's a good point @Eilon regarding the dev branch. However, why would it still break for NuGet.org? If I can solve this for beta2, then I can solve it in general.

Comment: If you use `master` right now you need to use nuget.org as your feed. If you use `dev` you need to use MyGet.org / aspnetvnext as your feed. The problem is that you can't mix and match. The ASP.NET team (my team) is working on fixing the dependencies to not use the format `1.0.0-*` because the `*` means "latest". We're instead going to lock the build versions, but that isn't done yet.

Comment: Okay, you are a rockstar for: 1) helping and being nice 2) being on the ASP.NET team. I propose we fix this for master. Then I take what you taught me for the dev. The problem is that this isn't working for me using the master. I used kpm restore to try to fix everything, but it seems to still have an issue. I'm updating my post as you suggest possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comments as an answer:

This is caused by a mismatch between the absolute newest packages versus the specific packages used by the copy of the MusicStore sample app that you have.

If you use the `master` branch of MusicStore right now you need to use nuget.org as your feed. If you use the `dev` branch you need to use MyGet.org / aspnetvnext as your feed. The problem is that you can't mix and match branches and feeds.

The ASP.NET team (my team) is working on fixing the dependencies to not use the format `1.0.0-*` because the `*` means "latest". We're instead going to lock the build versions, but that isn't done yet. For reference, here's an [example of a PR](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/1516/files) where the EntityFramework `master` branch is being fixed to hard-code `beta2` as the version.

Comment: Thank you @Eilon. That link is pure gold. It fixed my xunit problem. I am in the process of updating the packages to beta2 (right now the errors are still there in startup.cs). I assume this will fix my master (stay tuned). I know I am getting ahead of myself, but  do you have a PR for the dev branch? Or is that still going to work with * ?

Comment: That worked. Thank you. My only remaining question is the same. How would I define my project.json packages version for a dev branch? Do I work with * still but use the nightly build nugget?

Comment: @hlyates The `dev` branch always uses latest, so it always uses `*`.

Comment: If I have future (and I promise short questions), can I please have a quick way of contacting you? I.E, twitter, email, and etc? I am deeply appreciative of your help. I will test out dev today.

Comment: @hlyates I'm not much of a social networking person. Asking technical questions on StackOverflow is usually the best option.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I'll do my best to pay it forward if someone else runs into the same problem I did. :)